# Target parent div Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-poke">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="field"><a href="" class="active"></a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to add class to `.view-poke` when `<a></a>` has class `.active`

Comment: You can do like `if($("a").hasClass("active")){ //do }`

Comment: `$('.active').closest('.view-poke').addClass('someclass')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through each `a.active` class and add your Custom `class` to its `parent`

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.active').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.view-poke').addClass('customClass')
  })
})
```

```css
.customClass {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-poke">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field"><a href="" class="active">Anchor 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view-poke">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field"><a href="">Anchor 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view-poke">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field"><a href="" class="active">Anchor 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view-poke">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field">
      <a href=""></a>Anchor 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be you are looking for

```
$('a.active').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('.view-poke');
});
```